# CorePlot [CPTXYAxis setOrthogonalPosition] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Using CorePlot 2.1 I am experiencing the following error message

-[CPTXYAxis setOrthogonalPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x786c3740

No mater how much cleaning, re installing i do I always get this message

The code section is as follows;

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) graph.axisSet ;

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis ;
x.majorTickLength = 5.0;
x.minorTickLineStyle = nil ;
x.majorTickLineStyle= lineStyle;
x.majorIntervalLength = @(1.0);
x.orthogonalPosition = @(0.0);
```

Any thoughts gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
x.orthogonalPosition = @(0.0);
```

to

```
x.orthogonalPosition = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad - can you add a bit of context or explanation, to make it clear why this change will fix provide a solution?

Comment: I have seen its correct initialization here 
http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_x_y_axis.html#a5f1cc846c8aa0ff01f99bbab68b3ebdf

Comment: If you have additional information, then it should be included in your question - not just added as a comment. Ideally, any reader should be able to understand your entire answer without needing to read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

I still had  core-plot 1.5 still in my linked frameworks a libraries section of my project